# How can I find two repeating elements in an Array

Tags: java, arrays

Below code works fine but it is in the complexity of O(n^2). Is it possible to do it O(n) or O(log n) time.

```
public class TwoRepeatingElements {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer array[] = {4, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 2};
        findTwoRepeatingElements(array);


    }

    private static void findTwoRepeatingElements(Integer[] array) {
        int i, j;
        for(i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
            for(j = i+1; j < array.length-1; j++) {
                if(array[i] == array[j]) {
                    System.out.println(array[i]);
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have space/memory constraints or can you modify the list?

Comment: There is no space memory constraints.

Comment: There's no way to do this in O(log n) since you should always go over the entire array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution runs in O(n) time, notice that if you only need to find *one* repeated element, you can exit the loop as soon as you find it:

```
private static void findTwoRepeatingElements(Integer[] array) {
    Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (Integer i : array) {
        if (seen.contains(i))
            System.out.println(i);
        else
            seen.add(i);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you need to print the repeated elements only once, this solution uses a little more memory since two sets are needed, but it's still O(n). Take a look at this:

```
private static void findTwoRepeatingElements(Integer[] array) {

    Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Set<Integer> repeated = new HashSet<Integer>();

    for (Integer i : array)
        if (!seen.add(i) && repeated.add(i))
            System.out.println(i);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your code prints the output as `4 2 2` if array is `{4, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 2}`. I think it should print as `4 2 2`.

Comment: I don't understand the comment, the code prints exactly what you said it should: `4 2 2`

Comment: Anyway, I understood what you meant by looking the comments of the other answers, and I edited my solution above to give the answer that you needed. Please accept it if it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you can't find it in less than `O(n)`, since you need to scan the whole array.
You can use hastable for a `O(n)` solution.

Just insert your elements in a hastable as you go and stop when the element you are to insert is already there.

```
private static void findTwoRepeatingElements(Integer[] array) {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for(int a : array) {
        if(!set.add(a)) {
            System.out.println(a);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 as it's the solution I'd use given his comment of no memory limitation. These are very interview style questions and it's surprising how many can be easily break down to solutions with maps, hashes, and sets in my experiences.

Comment: But your code prints only 4 as an output if I take this as an array `{4, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1}`. I think it should print 4 and 2.

Comment: @Nevzz03 your question implies that you only care about finding any single duplicated item. You can easily modify the code to run through without breaking the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the array and then just look for two equal numbers in adjacent positions.

Comment: But it will be of order O(nlogn). I need something in O(n) or O(log n)

Comment: Nevzz03: You can't possibly go below O(n), since you'll have to look at every _n_ (element) in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary `hashmap` and put all values you encounter into this. The average look up time for a `hashmap` is O(1), thus you'd end with O(n).

Answer (score 0):

O(log n) is absolutely impossible, since you need to iterate over the entire array at least once.

If you know beforehand what range of integers are possible, and it's a relatively small range, you can use a `boolean[]` to keep track of what integers you've already seen. That would be O(n+k), where *k* is the size of the range, and therefore O(n) if *k* is in O(n). Otherwise, you can use a `HashSet<Integer>`, though that would not be *guaranteed* O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Peter's answer, but using the API better and thus with less code:

```
static Integer findFirstRepeatedElement(Integer[] array) {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for(Integer a : array) {
        if(!set.add(a)) // returns false if the element is already in the set
            return a;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Edited: I notice he has now fixed his previous non-leet implementation

Comment: This piece of code doesn't work if there're more than one repeated number and you want them all.

Comment: @Nevzz03 It's not meant to. It's only meant to demonstrate how to find the *first* duplicate. It could be modified to collect all duplicates - I'll leave that to you :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be reduced to O(n)

```
int previous =array[0];  
for(int i=1; i less than array.length; i++)    {
   if (previous == array[i] return true;    
   previous =array[i];    
}
return false // outside of loop.
```

Forgive the formatting I'm on my mobile